# How to make a link that POSTs and opens in a new window if the users chooses to do so?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, hyperlink

Usually links open in the same window or in a new tab depending on whether the users clicked or Ctrl+clicked. But when I have to POST, instead of GET, I have to create a form and put

```
href="javascript:document.forms['myForm'].submit()"
```

instead of the url. Is there any way in javascript to detect whether the user clicked or Ctrl+clicked so I can set the proper target for my form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest never to use the javascript protocol.

The onclick event can handle what you want and you can cancel the href

I like to use links for semantic and accessibility reasons instead of using a scripted span or similar

```
<a href="#" id="myFormSubmit">Submit</a>
```

or better:

```
<a href="javascriptrequired.html" id="myFormSubmit">Submit</a>
```

using

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("myFormSubmit").onclick=function(e) {
    var event = e?e:event, form = document.forms['myForm'];
    form.target = (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) ? '_blank' : '';// TJ/Jader Dias
    form.submit(); // or form.submitButton.click(); if any submit handler exists
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault(); 
    else return false; // cancel the click
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (e.preventDefault() e.preventDefault(); ` // syntax error

Comment: why do you `var event = e?e:event` and why do you `if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: (Older) IEs do not pass the event in the event handler but has a window.event. I just make sure the function has access to it. The test for preventDefault is to use it if it is available otherwise just return false - again to handle older browsers

Answer (score 1):

If you put a click handler on the link, you can look for the `ctrlKey` property on the event object. Here's the attribute version because you're doing something similar with the `href` (normally I tend to avoid using attributes for event handlers):

```
onclick="document.forms['myForm'].target = (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) ? '_blank' : ''"
```

E.g.:

```
<a href="javascript:document.forms['myForm'].submit()"
   onclick="document.forms['myForm'].target = (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) ? '_blank' : ''"
>...</a>
```

Or you can do the whole thing in the `onclick`:

```
<a href="#submitform"
   onclick="var form = document.forms['myForm']; form.target = (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) ? '_blank' : ''; form.submit(); return false;"
>...</a>
```